# Where does reference arr stored of arr = [1, 2, 3]?

Tags: python, c, pointers

Suppose such a snippet of C

```
//ptr_ops.c -- pointer operations
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
    int *ptr1, ptr2, ptr3;

    ptr1 = arr;
    printf("&ptr1 = %p, ptr1 = %p, *ptr1 = %d", &ptr1, ptr1, *ptr1);

    return 0;
}
```

It produces:

```
In [11]: !./a.out
&ptr1 = 0x7ffeeefc9790, ptr1 = 0x7ffeeefc97a0, *ptr1 = 100
```

I conclude that:

`ptr1 = 0x7ffeeefc97a0` is the `arr[]`'s address, `&ptr1` is where the pointer or the variable itself is stored.

As to python

```
In [12]: arr = [1, 2, 3]
In [13]: hex(id(arr))
Out[13]: '0x106065088'
```

'0x106065088' is the address of arr's value, how about the reference "arr", where does it stored?

Comment: Python doesn't expose the level of detail you are looking for. The value of `id(arr)` is *an* address, but it's an implementation detail; `id` only has to return a integer that is unique to `arr` while it is in scope. `arr` is simply a name that refers to an object on the heap, not a "thing" in itself.

Comment: Are you asking if Python supports pointers?

Comment: I guess that the reference should be stored somewhere rather than flying in the air @MadPhysicist

Comment: To cite Obi-Wan Kenobi: "You don’t need to see his identification.".

Comment: @rider. I've posted an answer to what I think your question is. It's still unclear what the question is, but your last comment seems to have a question in it.

Comment: You might consider thinking about what you are asking and rewording the question. If my interpretation is indeed correct, you have a fairly decent question here, one that I'm sure other people would be interested to read, but the presentation is abominable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References to top level names are bound through the namespaces of modules. If you are running in an interpreter, the module is called `__main__`. Modules will usually have a `__dict__` attribute that references a mapping of all the top level names (like`'arr'`) to actual object references (like whatever `arr` refers to).

In general, all names are stored in some kind of namespace. The basic types are object namespaces, which are relatively permanent and work either through `__dict__` or descriptors (e.g. `__slots__`), and function local namespaces, which exist only when the function is running. Modules and classes are objects with important namespaces, usually. There are rules for resolving a name when it isn't found in the local namespace. A common name for these rules is the acronym LEGB.

CPython does something called reference counting to know when to deallocate memory. When no more references to an object exist, it gets garbage collected and eventually deleted. Since this is an implementation detail of a particular interpreter, technically, an object can live in memory without *any* valid references to it (at least not ones accessible to the user, without any references at all, you would end up with a memory leak).